# Any artinian ring is coherent and perfect.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be an artinian ring.

We must prove that $R$ is also a coherent $R$ module.

In other words that every finitely generated ideal is finitely presented.

To show that $R$ is perfect I think we could use Bass P theorem, then we have to prove:

$\frac{R}{J(R)}$ is semisimple and $J(R)$ is $T$-nilpotent.

Comment: Uh, what is your definite of perfect then? Every book I have states bass theorem P in terms of the DCC on principal ideals, and the definition of perfectness in terms of T nilpotence, not the other way around.

Comment: the initial definition for a perfect ring in our book is one in which every left $R$-module has projective cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Bass' P theorem , then you are already done, because an Artinian ring clearly satisfies the DCC On principal ideals.  If you don't use Bass' theorem, then I still should be easy considering that $J(R)$ is a nilpotent ideal (hence $T$-nilpotent) and $J(R/J(R))=\{0\}$ (a basic result).

Coherence is also obvious: the kernel of a homomorphism leaving a finite rank free module is a submodule of a Noetherian module, hence it is finitely generated.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Now I only need to go back and re-read your solution.

Comment: In the coherence part I am a bit confused, wouldn't proving the kernel is finitely generated show the ideal is finitely related ?

Comment: I think that argument would work for any finitely generated module also :)

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Every right ideal of $R$ is going to be a homomorphic image of $R^n$, and the kernel of the homomorphism is f.g. That is f.p., not just f.r.

Comment: oh yeah, thank you very much.

Comment: so then every finitely generated module is finitely presented right?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Look, you can't just keep shifting your criteria all the time. What I said proves it for the characterization of "$R_R$ is a coherent module" as you originally stated. If you want to prove some other characterization, that's fine.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling The fact that $J(R/J(R))=\{0\}$ is proved in every algebra text introducing the Jacobson radical.

Comment: Oh no, I was just curious, I don't think we used anything other than the fact that the submodule is finitely generated to show it is finitely presented (for the coherent part)

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Well yes, that is correct, even right Noetherian rings are right coherent. You don't need the full weight of "right Artinian" to prove it. But if $R$ is only right noetherian, there's no way to prove $R/J(R)$ is Artinian. That's why $R$ being Artinian is important in this question.